# COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1' - even if utf8 is setup

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

In our database we store *everyting* with the character set utf8, and use `COLLATE utf8_general_ci`.

However, when querying data from **one** table, we always receive the following exception:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:978)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2530)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1907)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2030)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.CachedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(CachedPreparedStatement.java:111)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:80)
    ... 120 more
```

We cross checked everything we could imagine:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%char%';

character_set_client    utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database  utf8
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8
character_set_server    utf8
character_set_system    utf8
```

as well as

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%collation%';

collation_connection    utf8_general_ci
collation_database  utf8_general_ci
collation_server    utf8_general_ci
```

Also

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "ourscheme" and Character_set_name <> "utf8";

(empty result)
```

We ensured, client connections are using utf-8.

We are out of ideas. The table and column(s) are setup correctly it seems.

We also tried to explicit use the COLLATE in the query:

```
...table.column COLLATE utf8_general_ci AS 'column'
```

If we modify the query to THIS:

```
...table.column COLLATE latin1_general_ci AS 'column'
```

It works. How can it be, that mysql is showing utf8 EVERYWHERE - but the query fails and only works for latin1 collations?

The table in question is generated upon every application start, having as well explicit set the default charset and the default Collate.

Using the very same "code", we generate 8 more tables - where the problem is NOT existing.

Any Ideas? The envronment is :

- Wildfly 8.1
- MySQL 5.6.26 x64
- Hibernate 4.3.5.Final

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, found the cause - one of the columns we tried to `COLLATE utf8_general_ci` in the QUERY was actual a `bigint(20)` - Just always focused on the String-Columns, because the `bigint(20)` does not have setup a character set ofc - so I wouldn't have expected **that** exception message.

Comment: Do you remember how you found or how you discovered this?

Comment: @toddmetheny I compared the column types in the database with the query. Then it came to my attention.